# Can clients visit my site, and spam socket.emit(something); to my server, or is there some security behind socket.io?

Tags: server, vulnerability, client

I'm using Socket.IO and the client side looks like this.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.emit("sendData", "hello!");
</script>
```

I'm wondering what's stopping a random user, from joining my site, looking at the code, and add the following lines to it, using Chrome's code view app or something of the sorts:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        socket.emit("sendData", "hello!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A year ago I had the same problem, so I created this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket-anti-spam it basically keeps track of socket.id's spamming your socket.emit's and kicks them if they keep spamming. If they still persist then they get a temp ban. It's not a cover all because the bans are ip based though

Answer (score -1):

A bit of a loaded question really. However;

While that is a possibility, it is the nature of HTTP(S) & the WS(S) protocols. Making requests is just that, a request. In regards to the underlying question being posed regarding security...

For browser restrictions you are relying on the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), for injected content via [MITM attack vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) you should utilize the [wss (Web Socket Secrurity)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security) protocol which would then leave you with the typical [XSS attack vectors](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

These can be mitigated by using a combination of the [HTTP Security Headers](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers) implemented with the HTML5 specification and [sanitizing your input and output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_input_and_output_handling) which is best done with [character encoding](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation).

Comment: It sounds as if you are advocating a solution implemented in the browser.  The browser of a malicious user, which cannot be trusted to behave "properly".  The browser is controlled by the user and acts in the interest of that user (theoretically... while practically most users delegate that to browser development teams).  Not in the interests of your server, not in the interests of any other member of your site.